# Why doesn't this table look neat?

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image: a table with much rows and cols merged]

I want the base cells to be 20px per side. Then I want «merged cells» (with rowspan or colspan > 1) to have a size matching as much base cells they cover.

to achieve this I manually set the width of those merged cells. But in some configurations, it behaves strangely, like in the figure above.

the blue square covers 2x2 cells and is correctly sized. But the green square (and all the other large ones) is 5x2 and should be as large as its neighbour, 108px.

Why does chrome discard the dimensions I force ? (I didn't test other browsers)

You will find a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kjshk/

The HTML is as follows:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td colspan="9" rowspan="1" style="width: 196px; height: 20px; "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  colspan="8" rowspan="1" style="width: 174px; height: 20px; "></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td colspan="7" rowspan="2" style="width: 152px; height: 42px; "></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="width: 42px; height: 42px; background-color:blue "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="2" style="width: 108px; height: 42px; "></td>
            <td  colspan="5" rowspan="2" style="width: 108px; height: 42px; background-color:green "></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

---

**edit**:
I updated the jsFiddle with how It should look, but with an extra row which force correct sizes 
http://jsfiddle.net/kjshk/11/

---

**edit²**: I cannot really change the HTML structure, because it's generated dynamically (there a script which merge cells, in fact). So what I can act is on the style.

Comment: Because you are doing crazy things with colspan and rowspan. Run it through an HTML 5 [validator](http://validator.w3.org) for exciting errors such as *Row 6 of a row group established by a tbody element has no cells beginning on it.*

Comment: Please, for the love of whatever deity you worship, stop using tables for layout! It's 2012 for crying out loud!

Answer (score 0):

If you change percentage: does this help ?

```
<table
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td colspan="9" rowspan="1" style="width: 90%; height: 20px; "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  colspan="8" rowspan="1" style="width: 80%; height: 20px; "></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td colspan="7" rowspan="2" style="width: 70%; height: 42px; "></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="width: 20%; height: 42px; background-color:blue "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="2" style="width: 50%; height: 42px; "></td>
            <td  colspan="5" rowspan="2" style="width: 50%; height: 42px; background-color:green "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

how it should look:
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td colspan="9" rowspan="1" style="width: 196px; height: 20px; "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  colspan="8" rowspan="1" style="width: 174px; height: 20px; "></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td colspan="7" rowspan="2" style="width: 152px; height: 42px; "></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="width: 42px; height: 42px; background-color:blue "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="2" style="width: 108px; height: 42px; "></td>
            <td  colspan="5" rowspan="2" style="width: 108px; height: 42px; background-color:green "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: did you took account of the last <TR> I missed ? (I edited the post and removed it) . But this is'nt what I expected. the last row (with the green square)'s cells should have the same width

Comment: Same width means ? The 2 TD of row should have same width ? or it should be same as that of blue above ?

Comment: I've updated my post with a second jsFiddle which will be hopefully helpfull

Comment: You might want to specify width of first cell of 3rd row to 10%.

Answer (score 0):

Widths in table cells are always interpreted as guidelines instead of rules. `table-layout:fixed` enforces the rules.

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 20px" span="10" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll look into your solution later, I have to go now, thanks anyway