# dynamic flexible grid layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want dashboards layed out against a flexible grid with the following requirements:

- total width is variable, and must always fit the screen, even at resizes
- cells may be merged
- all columns should have the same size (example, with 3 columns)
- same with rows
- total height should optionnaly fit the screen height
- those grid are user generated, so they can't be CSS hard-coded like the online generators do.

Here's some pictures I've made:

**example of user defined grid**
[image: example of user defined grid]

**same example with merged cells**
[image: same example with merged cells]

**same example scaled**
[image: same example scaled]

I'm looking for a plugin/code to achieve that, as I'm almost sure it can't be done in CSS (grid layout is not implemented yet in most browsers, as far as I know).
The closest I got was generating a table, but sizing the cells ended up being a complete chaos ([why doesn't this table look neat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862312/why-doesnt-this-table-look-neat)).

Comment: I can't see any actual question, what are you asking? How to write the CSS, a site where this is done already?

Comment: there are numerous plugins available... what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried Masonry, but it rearranges items, When I just want the grid to be scaled down to fit screen

Answer (score 8):

You can get close to that by using a plugin like http://masonry.desandro.com/ or http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

For the responsive bit, I recommend reading http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout. It talks about the masonry plugin but the concepts can be universally applied.

Comment: Pinterest is what I'm trying to avoid. I don't understand how people call it a grid when it's just X columns. Masonry is the closest from what I'm looking for, but I don't want the rearranging thing.

Comment: There is also http://isotope.metafizzy.co/. it's a lot like masonry but you might be able to customise it to remove the rearranging thing.

Comment: I checked more deeply isotope and masonry and I think they have what I want in fluid/responsive categories except they don't offer vertical fit-to-screen resize

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what else I can suggest. I think you may have to pick one and customise it yourself.